# You are given a string equal halves and reverse it

Tags: arrays, string, reverse

```js
let n = "jsdfnsgnlewnl";
let l = n.length;
let trgt = Math.floor((l-1)/2);


function firstHalf(anyhting){
  let ans = [];
  for (i = trgt; i>=0; i--){
    ans.push(n[i])
  }
  return ans;
}


function lastHlaf (anyhting){
  let ansx = [];
  for (i=l-1; i>=trgt+1; i--){
    ansx.push(n[i])
  }
  return ansx;
}

let answer = firstHalf(n);
let answerx = lastHlaf(n);
let newAnswer = answer.join("");
let newAnswerx = answerx.join("");
console.log(newAnswer+newAnswerx)
```

in this code the output should be -> `snfdsjglnweln`

But it's giving --> `gsnfdsjlnweln`

Can anyone please explain me.

Thank you
for example -->
//if ithe input is odd like xyzakig
//then the middle value should not be changed please help me to understand the issue

Comment: This would likely be better asked on codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @computercarguy This post would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for Code review, because the code is not working as expected, and the OP is asking for an explanation of why that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaaahhh, with your comment concerning **odd** number of string-length, I think I understood now your question. Hence I edited my initial answer.

1. **Initial string** `jsdfnsgnlewnl` to devide into 2 parts

   We get **left half** `jsdfns` and **right half** `nlewnl`
2. **Then invert** each block seperately

   We get `snfdsj` and `lnweln`
3. **Check** if initial string-length **is odd**

   If so, we define the middle element, here `g`
4. **Then join** the 2 strings (or 3 strings if odd)

   We get `snfdsjglnwelng`

Now we get your requested result: `snfdsjglnweln`

The following code would give you the expected output:

```js
let n = "jsdfnsgnlewnl";
let l = n.length;
let trgt = Math.floor(l/2); // '(l/2) instead of '((l-1)/2)'

let even = Number.isInteger(l/2); // check if 'l' is an even number

function firstHalf(anyhting){
  let ans = [];                 // index 'i' is zero-based:  
  for (i = trgt-1; i>=0; i--){  // 'trgt-1' instead of 'trgt'
    ans.push(n[i])
  }
  return ans;
}

function lastHalf (anyhting){  // corrected typo: 'lastHalf' instead of 'lastHlaf'
  let ansx = [];
  for (i=l-1; i>l-1-trgt; i--){ // 'i>l-1-trgt' instead of 'i>=trgt-1'
    ansx.push(n[i])
  }
  return ansx;
}

let answerMiddle = "";
if (!even) answerMiddle = n[trgt]; // define the "letter in the middle" if odd


let answer = firstHalf(n);
let answerx = lastHalf(n);
let newAnswer = answer.join("");
let newAnswerx = answerx.join("");

console.log(newAnswer + answerMiddle + newAnswerx)  // add also '+answerMiddle'
```

I tested for even string-lengths as well - worked. Hope I got it right now.

Comment: if ithe input is odd like xyzakig //then the middle value should not be changed please help me to understand the issue

Comment: @06xx97 I edited my answer according to your clarification in your comment. Please review and let us know whether this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @06xx97 As you are new, please mark your question as answered if you feel that your problem has been resolved. Thus other members of the community would know that your issue has been solved - thank you.

Comment: sorry i forgot that thank you for your help once again